# Comparing CSV files in Beyond Compare 3: How to ignore/filter out lines that don't exist on right i.e. only show lines with mismatched data

Tags: csv, beyondcompare, beyondcompare3

Am comparing two CSV files, one of which (the right) is mostly a sorted subset of the left file.  Am trying to see only the lines of the files with mismatching data *not* lines which exist only on the left.  I can do this in the folder compare, but not in the file compare (i.e. I can ignore files on the left that aren't on the right, but not lines in a file compare).  Is there a way to do this?

Example:
left file:
1,2,3
4,5,6

right file:
4,5,7

I want to see only the mismatch of "4,5,6" with "4,5,7" and for "1,2,3" to be ignored as it doesn't exist in the right.  This sort of assumes the file data is sorted in both files to some degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the Data Compare's toolbar and select Toggles to change the filter button type. Then turn off the Left filter button to hide differences that are only on the left.

To restore the filter buttons to the default, right click on the toobar and select Favorites.

Comment: Awesome thank you!!  I knew it was there somewhere I just couldn't find it.  Beyond Compare has never once let me down.